# Reactjs req.body shows [object Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs

i have a http put function in ReactJs that looks like this

```
UpdateItem: function(_id) {
      var input = this.refs.myInput;
        $.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/update/' + _id,
  type: 'PUT',
  data:input,
  cache: false,
  success: function(result) {
    console.log(data);
      window.location.reload();
  }
});
          }
```

it takes an input and it should send the new value with the request but the it never does

```
<input ref="myInput" type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="10" defaultValue={item.quantity}  className="form-control"/>
```

when i look at the console the req.body shows this [object Object] and my put function in node looks like this

```
app.put('/update/:_id', function(req, res) {
      console.log(req.params);
      console.log("your req is" +req.body);
      Cart.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { quantity: req.body.quantity }, function(err, product) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(product);

  console.log(product);
});
     });
```

any ideas of what the problem could be ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you are trying to concatenate a string with an object. That's what the `+`-sign does in your `console.log`.

You'll notice that `console.log(req.body)` and `console.log("your req is")` both work individually, but `console.log("your req is" + req.body)` will give you the wrong output.

To fix this, either do two separate outputs, or use this:

```
console.log("your req is", req.body);
```

Now you'll get both the string and the Object properties to output in the console.

#### Demo:

**(check the output in the console)**

```js
var person = {name: "Bob", sirname: "Smith", age: 34};

console.log("The person data is: ", person); //right
console.log("The person data is: " + person); //wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

It just saying that your "req.body" is some kind of Object, which it should be.

If you want to see what is inside, this can be handy :

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))
```